# Finding items satisfying a condition in a list using patterns

Tags: pattern-matching, filtering

Why the following command

```
Cases[{1, 2, 6, 3, 4, 8, 5}, {x_, y_, z_} /; (y > Max[x, z]):>y]
```

doesn't return the y values that are greater than their neighbors in the list?
I am expecting to have an output like {6,8}.

Comment: For this question, I want to know how can I do it using patterns and I am not looking for alternative solutions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are no `List`s of length 3 in the input at level 1. So `Cases` cannot find anything. However `SequenceCases` can because it interprets lists as sequences.

```
SequenceCases[
 {1, 2, 6, 3, 4, 8, 5}, 
 {x_, y_, z_} /; (y > Max[x, z]) :> y, 
 Overlaps -> True
 ]
```

> {6, 8}

Comment: But why this one Cases[{1, 6, 4}, {x_, y_, z_} /; (y > Max[x, z]) :> y] also doesn't work? I have a list of length 3 in level 1.

Comment: Because the list is still not on level one. But `Cases[{{1, 6, 4}}, {x_, y_, z_} /; (y > Max[x, z]) :> y] ` does return `{6}`. Reading [this](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/LevelsInExpressions.html) might give you the whole picture.

Answer (score 3):

[`ReplaceList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceList.html) with a slight modification of the pattern in OP gives the desired result:

```
ReplaceList[{1, 2, 6, 3, 4, 8, 5}, {___, x_, y_, z_, ___} /; (y > Max[x, z]) :> y]
```

> {6, 8}

Answer (score 2):

The approach proposed in the question works well with a slight modification.

```
Cases[Partition[{1, 2, 6, 3, 4, 8, 5}, 3, 1], {x_, y_, z_} /; (y > Max[x, z]) :> y]
(* {6, 8} *)
```

There are many other approaches as well, for instance,

```
list = {1, 2, 6, 3, 4, 8, 5};
MapThread[If[#1 > Max[#2, #3], #1, Nothing] &, 
    {list[[2 ;; -2]], list[[1 ;; -3]], list[[3 ;; -1]]}]
(* {6, 8} *)
```

**Timing**

Runtime for the `MapThread` solution with a `list` of length of 40000 is, for instance,

```
list = RandomInteger[{0, 9}, 40000];
AbsoluteTiming[MapThread[If[#1 > Max[#2, #3], #1, Nothing] &, 
    {list[[2 ;; -2]], list[[1 ;; -3]], list[[3 ;; -1]]}][[1 ;; 10]]]
```

about 0.06 seconds on my computer and increases approximately linearly with the length of `list`.  The solution using `Cases` and  `Partition` requires about the same amount of time.  Surprisingly, the solution with `ReplaceList` is about two orders of magnitude slower and increases approximately quadratically with the length of `list`.  The solution using `SequenceCases` is many orders of magnitude slower and increases at least cubically with the length of `list`.